# How to pass twig parameters through FormBuilder's fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I've implemented the help messages in forms as in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#adding-help-messages)

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block field_widget %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% if help is defined %}
        <span class="help">{{ help }}</span>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

To render the help section, the example says that 'help' should be defined in the twig file as in:

```
{{ form_widget(form.title, {'help': 'foobar'}) }}
```

However, I'd like to define 'help' as an option for the fields in the form builder, like this:

```
class myClassType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title',null,array('help'=>'foobar'));
    }
}
```

This has yield no results ("The option "help" does not exist "). I've also tried

```
$builder
   ->add('title',null,array('attr'=>array(help'=>'foobar')));
```

and it doesn't work either.

Any ideas to get something like this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
$builder
->add('title',null,array('attr'=>array('help'=>'foobar')));
```

And then

```
{% if attr['help'] is defined %}
    <span class="help">{{ attr['help'] }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: One small downside is that input fields will also have `help='foobar'`  set on it which is redundant IMHO.

Comment: Thanks I was looking for a way to pass custom parameters to a custom twig ```block```. I did it through ```attr['help']``` as you suggest here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533159/defining-custom-twig-form-block-for-errors-rendering

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize `finishView` method of `AbstractType` which ultimately implements `FormTypeInterface`. e.g,

```
// Vendor/YourBundle/Form/Type/YourFormType

namespace Vendor\YourBundle\Form\Type;

// other use definitions
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

class YourFormType extends AbstractType 
{
    // other methods.... 

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        parent::finishView($view, $form, $options);
        $view['title']->vars['help'] = "Title help message";
        // same for other fields
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the reason you cannot do this is that form field help text is largely a view/templating concern. I realize this does not answer your question entirely.