# Defining custom twig form block for errors rendering

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I'm trying to define a specific new block for form field errors rendering, keeping form_errors unchanged for common errors rendering.

```yaml
# Twig Configuration
twig:
  debug:            %kernel.debug%
  strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    form:
      resources:
        - 'ApplicationMyBundle:Main:form/customFormTheme.html.twig'
```

In `customFormTheme.html.twig` I overwrite a few blocks copied from `form_div_layout.html.twig` plus I added the folloowing new one.

```html
{% block field_errors %}{% spaceless %}
        {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in errors %}
                {% if error.messageTemplate|length %}
                <li class="error">{{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators') }}</li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}{% endblock %}
```

Then I expect to be able to use this block in my views like this :

```twig
 <div>
     {{ form_label(form.message, 'message.label'|trans({},'contact')|raw ) }}
     {{ form_widget(form.message, {attr: {maxlength:1000, size:1000, rows:8}}) }}
     {{ field_errors(form.message) }}
 </div>
```

but I receive the following error :

`The function "field_errors" does not exist. Did you mean "form_errors"`

I also tried by naming my block `text_errors` or `textarea_errors` mentioned **[here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#template-fragment-inheritance)** but I haven't been luckier.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it works by defining the block `text_errors` or `textarea_errors` only and still use `{{ form_errors(field.name) }}` in your template. If a block named after the type of your field exists (**[according to form field types](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html)**) it will be used instead of `form_errors`.

**!! But you can't use directly `{{ text_errors(field.name) }}` in your twig template !!**

The same way you can have a custom row for a specific type like this

```
{% block textarea_row %}{% spaceless %}
    <div class="textarea l-field {{ (form_errors(form)?'error':'') }}">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}{% endblock textarea_row %}
```

and use it in your template as follow :

```
{# message has textarea field type #}

{{ form_row(form.message, {
    label: 'message.label'|trans({},'contact')|raw ,
    attr: {maxlength:1000, size:1000, rows:8}})
}}
```

You can also pass many custom parameters by using the object attr{}

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="form-field {{ (form_errors(form)?'error':'') }}">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ dump(attr) }}
        {% if attr.help is defined and not attr.help == '' %}<p class="form-help">{{ attr.help }}</p>{% endif %}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

and use it like this

```
{{ form_row(form.message, {
       label: 'message.label'|trans({},'contact')|raw ,
       attr: {
           maxlength:1000, size:1000, rows:8,
           help: 'password.help'|trans({})|raw
       }
   })
}}
```

Comment: I'm still missing a way to had custom parameters to test in my custom block and have further customisations possible like ```with help:"A custom legend for the field"```.

Comment: I figured out how to do so by using attr object. I edited my answer. Cheers